# Delete specific folders in many folders and subfolders

Tags: loops, powershell, directory

So I've noticed that Windows creates hidden folders called "blabla.jpg.files" if you have enabled the thumbnail view in your picture folder. I sync my picture folder to my phone and NAS and would like to remove those hidden folders from there with powershell.

Since my picture folder also has subfolders which also have subfolders and so on, I would like to create a little loop.

The script should just scan in all subfolders of one folder for hidden folders with the name "*.files" and remove them.

Can somebody help me with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create loop as Get-ChildItem can search recursively for the specified item e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem <path> -r -attributes h+d *.files | Remove-Item -r -whatif
```

The above command requires features that are new in PowerShell v3.  If the list of folders to be deleted looks correct, remove the `-whatif` to actually delete them.

BTW I don't see that Windows creates these folders on my system.  It does create a hidden file called Thumbs.db.  Perhaps it is some other program that is creating these hidden folders?